# Error: Cannot resolve module 'Json-loader' whilst using webpack with express

Tags: javascript, json, express, webpack

I am trying to use webpack with express but have encountered some errors.
This is the error I am currently getting: `Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader'`

package.json: (json loader in both, as is webpack and config etc)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "firebase": "^3.3.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "webpack-config": "^6.1.2"
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
      ]
    }

}
```

As can be seen above, I have json loader there and have entry pointing to my app.js that looks like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var firebase = require('firebase');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/welcome', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/welcome.html');
});
```

What am i doing wrong? i.e. how do I get rid of the error and make express work with webpack?

Comment: Did you actually _install_ the package?

Comment: yes `npm install json-loader` correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Try replace your `json-loader` with `webpack-node-externals` https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

Comment: Is this your_entire_ `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, and this is how I fixed it. Note that this solution might not fix @Waterman1's issue, unless my guess that we're not seeing the entire `webpack.config.js` is correct.

(1)
install / add to `package.json` `json-loader`

(2)
edit `webpackage.json.js`
changing (this may vary slightly for you)

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
    loaders: ['eslint-loader'],
    exclude: ['node_modules']
  }
  ],
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
    loaders: ['babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  }
  ]
}
```

to

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
    loaders: ['eslint-loader'],
    exclude: ['node_modules',/\.json$/]
  }
  ],
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: "json-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
    loaders: ['babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  }
  ]
}
```

In particularly noting the changes:

- adding `loader-json` first to `loaders`
- adding `/\.json$/` to `exclude` in the `preLoaders`